# Geometric interpretation for a connection whose corresponding distribution generates the whole Lie algebras of vector fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections, curvature, sub-riemannian-geometry

Let we have a connection on a manifold $M$ so it is  considered as a distribution on the  tangent bundle $TM$ of $M$. The integrability of this distrbution is equivalent to flatness of the connection.

What is a geometric interpretation of the opposit situation: The situation that the distributation is totally non integrable in the sense that the Lie algebra generated by all  locall vector field tangent to the distribution is the   whole  lie algebra  of  local vector fields on $TM$